# Queue implementation display function error

Tags: python, queue

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):   '''initialization of function'''
        self.items = []
    def is_empty(self):   '''Checking if queue is empty or not'''
        return self.items == []
    def enqueue(self, data): '''Adding value '''
        self.items.append(data)
    def dequeue(self):     ''' Removing value'''
        return self.items.pop(0)
    def dis(self):  '''Printing the stored item in queue'''
        print(items)
```

After that initialization of `Queue`:

```
 q = Queue()
 while True:
     print('enqueue <value>')
     print('dequeue')
     print('dis')
     print('quit')
     do = input('What would you like to do? ').split()
     operation = do[0].strip().lower()
     if operation == 'enqueue':
         q.enqueue(int(do[1]))
     elif operation == 'dequeue':
         if q.is_empty():
             print('Queue is empty.')
         else:
             print('Dequeued value: ', q.dequeue())
     elif operation == 'dis':
         q.dis()
     elif operation == 'quit':
         break
     else:
         print("Enter the correct operation")
```

I'm not able to display the items which are enqueued in the `Queue`. How could I use `dis()` method to display items in it?

Comment: I think you mean print(self.items)

Comment: Yes the dis method

Comment: The dis method does not do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Queue:
    items=[]
    size=5
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items == []
    def enqueue(self, data):
        self.items.append(data)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.items.pop(0)
    def dis(self):
        print(self.items)
    def is_full(self):
        if (len(self.zitems)>5):
            print("Queue is full")
        else:
            print("Not full")
```

Inizialize the items=[] and in dis method add self.items.Also, you could check if the size of the queue is full or not

Answer (score 4):

Think you should print self.items (instead of items)

```py
def dis(self):  '''Printing the stored item in queue'''
    print(self.items)
```

That'll output the list using standard formatting, not very pretty so you'll probably want to add some extra logic for pretty-printing.

If you want to restrict the queue size, you could do this by simply ignoring items past a certain limit. For this you'll need to implement a limit, along with logic for checking the limit. For example:

```py
class Queue:
    def __init__(self, size=8):   '''initialization of function'''
        self.items = []
        self.size = size
    def is_empty(self):   '''Checking if queue is empty or not'''
        return self.items == []
    def enqueue(self, data): '''Adding value '''
        if len(self.items) < self.size:
            self.items.append(data)
        else:
            pass # behavior when queue is already full
    def dequeue(self):     ''' Removing value'''
        return self.items.pop(0)
    def dis(self):  '''Printing the stored item in queue'''
        print(items)
```

Comment: Can you help to set limit on size of queue